# Гарантия того, что сборщик будет вызван до того, как иссякнет память

Tags: .net, сборщик-мусора

Если я правильно помню теорию, то GC крутится в отдельном потоке.

Предположим, у нас много потоков с высоким приоритетом, которые сильно мусорят.

Дается ли какая-то гарантия со стороны CLR, что сборщик получит квант времени на то, что бы запустить процесс сборки мусора до того, как место иссякнет?

Есть предположение, на каждый `new` CLR проверяет доступное место и если его нет, то принуддительно запускается сборщик мусора. Но подтверждение этому я не нашел.

Comment: Что мешает его вызывать в ручную, когда это требуется? А так, нет никаких гарантий!

Answer (score 2):

> Есть предположение, на каждый `new` CLR проверяет доступное место и если его нет, то принуддительно запускается сборщик мусора. Но подтверждение этому я не нашел.

Насколько я понял, так и происходит. [Garbage Collection Design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/docs/design/coreclr/botr/garbage-collection.md):

> The allocator is designed to achieve the following:
>
> - Triggering a GC when appropriate: The allocator triggers a GC when the allocation budget (a threshold set by the collector) is exceeded or when the allocator can no longer allocate on a given segment.

По поводу:

> Предположим, у нас много потоков с высоким приоритетом, которые сильно мусорят.
>
> Дается ли какая-то гарантия со стороны CLR, что сборщик получит квант времени на то, что бы запустить процесс сборки мусора до того, как место иссякнет?

в документации написано (раздел Functional Behavior), что, в зависимости от типа GC (`Workstation` / `Server`), GC будет немного по разному работать, но во всех случаях CLR приостанавливает потоки на время (`GC calls SuspendEE to suspend managed threads`).

Отличие составляет только в `WKS GC with concurrent GC on` или `SVR GC with concurrent GC on` у них происходит очистка в отельном потоке, но все равно он сначала приостанавливает все потоки, запускает фоновый GC и возобновляет потоки обратно.

Если же все равно закончилась память, то будет происходить очистка так в однопоточном режиме. (`User thread may run out of allocation budget and trigger an ephemeral GC (what we call a foreground GC). This is done in the same fashion as the "WKS GC with concurrent GC off" flavor`).